# Show german "umlauts" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, encoding, drawer

In my Drawer() in Flutter I try to display German umlauts (Ä, Ö, Ü). Unfortunately, in my Android emulator and in the browser, it shows a ? at the respective place:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoATb.png)

**Code snippet:**

```
ListTile(
  title: const Text('Änderungen'),
  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
),
ListTile(
  title: const Text('Öffentlich'),
  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
),
ListTile(
  title: const Text('Einstellungen'),
  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
),
```

Does anyone have an idea what I have to set so that German umlauts are displayed correctly?

Comment: which font are u using?
For me on my android/ios emulator default font correctly shows symbols

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't actually changed anything on the default. To be on the safe side, I have now added the Google font Roboto to my Flutter project and set the style properties accordingly. but unfortunately the same problem:

`ListTile(title: const Text('Änderungen', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 30.0), ),  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context), ),`

Comment: I found the mistake. it wasn't the font, it was the encoding setting in my Visual Studio Code. After I set this to UTF-8, re-entered the umlauts and restarted VS Code, the characters were displayed correctly.

my bad...